# How to add a profile picture to my Stack Overflow profile

Tags: discussion

I have created a profile on Stack Overflow recently. But my profile is showing a blank-avatar. How can I add my pic to the profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profile page -> Edit Profile & Settings tab -> Change Picture link

Comment: But it can be that your reputation is too low to have such privilege.

Comment: Thank You. I have added the pic :-) I had tried it earlier, but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: But, the same is not updating on careers-stackoverflow. That is where I wanted to change the profile pic. Any ideas Elgin?

Answer (score 4):

Step 1> Click on account info[image: account info] to go to your profile

Step 2> click on Edit Profile & Settings[image: Edit Profile & Settings]

Step 3> click on Change picture[image: Change picture]